# Waiting Time Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable which denotes the amount of time spent in a state(say state 'I') before changing state. 
As X is a random variable it must have a Probability space/sample space and a sigma field/sigma algebra and I am not able to figure out what these are.

Comment: Presumably $X$ can take values in positive (or perhaps non-negative) $\mathbb{R}$ and you could use the Borel $\sigma$-algebra or  Lebesgue measurable sets

Comment: These are irrelevant. All that matters is 1. a general result ensuring that they exist and 2. the distribution of the random variable X. That one focusses on the identity of the probability space is an unfortunate effect of some misleading curricula.

Comment: @Did I didn't get your last sentence - "That one focusses on the identity of the probability space is an unfortunate effect of some misleading curricula". Can you explain that please

Comment: One sees countless exercises asking to specify some set Omega, sigma-algebra F and probability P such that one can define a random variable X on the probability space (Omega,F,P) with some desired distribution mu. None of them is useful, neither in practice nor in theory. First, many probability spaces (Omega,F,P) are fitting. Second, in most situations, Omega=[0,1], F Borel sigma-algebra, P Lebesgue measure, fits. Third, solving actual problems only requires to know that such (Omega,F,P) exists on which one can define X with the desired distribution... and then to work on the problem itself!